# How to create Connection Factory in Websphere

Tags: queue, ibm-mq, websphere-7, mq

I am trying to use Queue-s, so I need to set a Connection Factory, and Queue.

But at the beggining, I can't go forward. I can't set the Connection Factory.

I am using this link to set up a connection factory:
[link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.dserver.z.config/Content/Business_Rules/_pubskel/Infocenter_Primary/ps_DSz_Configuring2198.html)

But at the 9th step I don't know what to set, this is the interface to set:
[image: picture]

If I set "localhost" to Hostname, then click NEXT and trying to test it, I get this message:

> A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following
>   reason: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2'
>   ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE').

So.. How could create a connection factory?

Answer (score 1):

The transport should not be client if you are trying to connect to a local qmgr in bindings mode.  The application server will access the qmgr using IPC.

If you are trying to connect as a client then TCP will be used in that case you need to specify the port where the qmgr listener is listening and the SVRCONN (server connection) channel to use.